# melt equivalent of pivot_longer with multiple name patterns

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

I'm currently translating an app in data.table syntax and came across a `pivot_longer`, where the column names get seperated into two columns based on a pattern:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)

dt <- data.table(id = 1:5, abc_123 = runif(5), def_456 = runif(5))
dt %>% pivot_longer(-id, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("char", "num"))

# A tibble: 10 × 4
#      id char  num     value
#   <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1     1 abc   123   0.902  
# 2     1 def   456   0.763  
# 3     2 abc   123   0.00490
# 4     2 def   456   0.471  
# 5     3 abc   123   0.647  
# 6     3 def   456   0.742  
# 7     4 abc   123   0.730  
# 8     4 def   456   0.0154 
# 9     5 abc   123   0.207  
#10     5 def   456   0.764
```

I tried to supply the patterns to `measure.vars = patterns()`, however, it seems that with `melt` only the values can seperated into different columns, not the variable names.

Is there an equivalent way of doing this with `data.table`?

Comment: You can use reshape or gather and spread to accomplish the same functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, the separation of (variables') names can be done in melt only in the dev version of data.table.

You can install a dev version by running `data.table::update_dev_pkg()`.

### Using dev version

```
melt(dt, id="id", measure=measure(char, num, pattern="(.*)_(.*)"))
```

In case you would like to convert `num` into a numerical variable, then you can use `as.numeric` (The same logic applies with `char` in case you like to convert it into a factor). The new code becomes

```
melt(dt, id="id", measure=measure(char, num=as.numeric, pattern="(.*)_(.*)"))

#        id   char   num      value
#     <int> <char> <num>      <num>
#  1:     1    abc   123 0.08764793
#  2:     2    abc   123 0.21928681
#  3:     3    abc   123 0.07032364
#  4:     4    abc   123 0.67780733
#  5:     5    abc   123 0.80658605
#  6:     1    def   456 0.43035816
#  7:     2    def   456 0.41987074
#  8:     3    def   456 0.70536835
#  9:     4    def   456 0.14457836
# 10:     5    def   456 0.53833383
```

### Using released version

```
melt(dt, id="id", measure=patterns("_")) |> 
  _[, c("char", "num") := tstrsplit(variable, "_", type.convert=TRUE)] |> 
  _[, variable := NULL]
```

Comment: good to know that feature is in place in the dev version, that's cool! +1!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `melt` alone can make it but you can try `tstrsplit` along with it.

I hope this should be close to what `pivot_longer` does

```
melt(dt, id = "id")[
    ,
    c("char", "num") := tstrsplit(variable, "_")
][
    ,
    variable := NULL
][]
```

which gives

```
    id     value char num
 1:  1 0.8966972  abc 123
 2:  2 0.2655087  abc 123
 3:  3 0.3721239  abc 123
 4:  4 0.5728534  abc 123
 5:  5 0.9082078  abc 123
 6:  1 0.2016819  def 456
 7:  2 0.8983897  def 456
 8:  3 0.9446753  def 456
 9:  4 0.6607978  def 456
10:  5 0.6291140  def 456
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering the question!